# coding a server on using restlet 2.0

Tags: restlet-2.0

I am coding a server for a project of mine using restlet 2.0. I have a java class which starts the server (starting it on a port and all those stuff). I am stuck at a point where i need to map the uri's of different services i intend to offer. If i were to include uri mapping part in a servlet how do i go about it. what are the changes i need to make in the web.xml. i have found very little documentation regarding this.
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the routing configuration must be done in your Restlet application class. You need to override the createInboundRoot method to attach your resources to paths, as described below:

```
public class MyRestletApplication extends Application {
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        Router router = new Router(getContext());
        router.attach("/path/{id}", MyServerResource.class);
        (...)
        return router;
    }
}
```

The configured resources can be then reached through the configured Restlet server. For example, with the address http://localhost:8082/path/12 if you implement your Restlet server as following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Server server = new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8182);
        server.setNext(new MyRestletApplication());
        server.start();
        (...)
    } catch(Exception ex) {}
}
```

Restlet also provides a servlet adapter with its org.restlet.ext.servlet extension. The latter allows using the ServerServlet servlet in order to access the configured resources. When configuring this servlet you need to specify the application class to use (the application contains the paths for your resources) through the org.restlet.application context parameter. The servlet can be configured as every servlet and be mapped on the /* pattern, as described below:

```
<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
        <param-value>org.restlet.example.MyApplication</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

In this case, your RESTful application implemented with Restlet will be accessed through a servlet container. In this case, your application needs to be packaged as a Java EE web application and will be reached with address: http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/path/12.

Hope it'll help you.
Thierry